# List database from different worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have several sheets, each containing serial codes in column AI (starting in cell AI14 and going down to AI400).

I am trying to make a summary sheet where all these serial codes are automatically populated under the respective sheet names.

So far, I tried using the INDIRECT formula: =INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!AI14") where B2 contains the sheet name for the formula to be directed to. As you may have realized, drag down does not work as AI14 does not change and, hence, I am repeatedly getting the value in cell AI14.

I am hesitant to use VBA as I am preparing a template for general use and I want it to be light. But if need be, then I am open to VBA.

Please help if possible. Thank you for your time!

Comment: do you have the same, fixed number of codes in all of the sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AI14 is between "" it does not increment while moving the formula, it is fixed not dynamic, to make it dynamic you need to include Row() row number will increment depending of the position of the cell.
Your formula will become:

`=INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!AI"&Row())`
if the formula is in Row 14 for example and you want to read AI14 no need to change anything and when you copy it down it will increment 14, 15,...
But in case the formula is in Row 10 and you need AI14 modify it to:
`=INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!AI"&Row()+4)`